# Replacing a specific content creation with the newest version

Tags: views, 8

[image]

I'm creating a website that tracks users weight. A user can create content to enter their weight and I have a view that displays all entries of a users weight however I want it so that if a user makes two entries on a single day that only the most recent from that day is shown and all the rest are not.

I have tried limiting the date but no success.

Comment: What is the structure where the weight entered? Is it a new node every time, or is it a multi-value field within a node? Thank you for the screenshot, but it would be better if it were a bit larger ;) You upload large images, the system will scale them down to fit with the option to view whole.

Comment: I am not sure that using nodes to track the user's weight is a good use of nodes.

Comment: @kiamlaluno do you have any other ways you can recommend?

Comment: Until the User entity doesn't have revisions, it's better to use custom code. Once the User entity has revisions, a user field would be sufficient.